# Recurrence Solution

Tags: recurrence-relation

What's the (asymptotic) solution of the recurrence $T(n,m,k,t)\leq T(n^\frac 1 m, 1, km, kt) + \Theta(n)$?

I know how to solve univariate recurrences, but this recurrence is much more difficult, so I am stuck here.

**Edit:**
The solution of this inequality should be something that does not imply any "dependency" between $n,m,k,t$. For example, subtituting the solution $T(n,m,k,t)=n^\frac k m$ yields $n^\frac m k\leq n^k$ which is true for every $n,m,k,t\geq 1$, while $T(n,m,k,t)=nk$ implies $nk\leq n^\frac 1 m km$ which is equaivalent to $n\leq n^\frac 1 m m$ which is not always true, and thus implies some dependency between $n,m$. Therefore, this solution holds only in special cases that satisfy this dependency.

I believe that the set of solutions of this inequality is a *subset* of the set of solutions that @D.W. has shown (as some of which are true only assuming some dependency between $m,n,k,t$).

Comment: What is/are the base case(s)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: 1) Calling this thing a recurrence is stretching terminology. 2) What do you know about how the parameters relate to each other? Why is $T$ well-defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't enough information to provide a solution.  See explanation below.

Let $c>0$ be a constant so that $T(n,m,k,t) \le T(n^{1/m},1,km,kt) + cn$.  When we unroll your recurrence twice, we find that

$$T(n,m,k,t) \le T(n^{1/m},1,km,kt) + cn \le T(n^{1/m},1,km,k^2mt) + 2cn.$$

Unroll $r$ times, and we find that

$$T(n,m,k,t) \le T(n^{1/m},1,km,k^r m^{r-1} t) + rcn.$$

This terminates at a base case when $k^r m^{r-1} t = 1$, which is equivalent to $(km)^r = m/t$.  Taking logs, we find that this happens when

$$r = {\log(m/t) \over \log(km)}.$$

Thus we find

$$T(n,m,k,t) \le T(n^{1/m},1,km,1) + {\log(m/t) \over \log(km)}cn.$$

Let $f(x,y)$ be a function of $x,y$.  Then

$$T(n,m,k,t) = \Theta(f(n^{1/m},km) + {\log(m/t) \over \log(km)}n)$$

is a possible solution of this recurrence (simply take $T(x,1,y,1) = f(x,y)$), as is any asymptotically smaller function.  To determine whether this is actually a feasible solution, plug into the definition above and check whether it satisfies your inequality for all $n,m,k,t$.

Is there a solution that is polynomial in $n$?  Yes, for instance $T(n,m,k,t) = n$ is easily verified to satisfy your inequality for all $n,m,k,t$ and to be polynomial in $n$.  Also $T(n,m,k,t)=n^2$ or indeed $T(n,m,k,t)=n^d$ for any constant $d$ is a solution.

Comment: Do you have any assumptions on $f$? (because taking $f(x,y)=\Theta(1)$, for example, gives a wrong solution to my understanding)

Comment: @DudiFrid, why do you think that gives a wrong solution?  It looks to me like the resulting solution is consistent with all of the information in the question.

Comment: Taking $f(x,y)=c$ for some constant $c$, gives $c+\frac {\log(m/t)}{\log (km)}n\leq d+\frac {\log(1/kt)}{\log (km)}n^\frac 1 m$ for some constant $d$. Thus, $\log(m/t)n\leq d+n^\frac 1 m$, but assuming that the inputs of $T$ (i.e, $n,m,k,t$) are "independent", we get inequality that is not true, because it shows a dependency between them. Thus, I think that the inequality in my post that shows no dependency between these inputs,  is not equivalent to what you've written.

Comment: @DudiFrid, if you forgot to include something in the question, please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: OK, I edited my question

Comment: My problem with your answer is in the first edit. In the second edit I added another closely-related question which is actually my motivation for this question.

Comment: @DudiFrid, OK, now I understand -- sorry to take a while to follow you.  I've updated my answer accordingly; now I think it might be a valid answer to your question.

Comment: Regarding my second question (if there is a polynomial solution) : $T(n,m,k,t)=n$ does not satisfy the requirement $T(n,m,k,t)=\omega(n)$ (I first posted $\Omega(n)$; this was a mistake, and I fixed it). On the other hand, $n^2$ is not a solution to the inequality as this yields $n^2\leq n^\frac 2 m$, which is wrong unless $m\leq 1$ and I do not assume this; I do assume some other assumptions that appear in my post in my second edition.